# Calculating limit approaches inifnity having infinite terms

Tags: calculus, limits

On my sample calculus mid-term exam, there is a weird question that asks us to calculate the limit that has an infinite term:

$\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} {\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+...+\frac{1}{n+n}}$

I am not sure what kind of technique should be used here.

Giving that this is mid-term of the first-year university calculus exam, we have only learned L'hopital's Rule and other basic techniques. But I don't see any technique that can fit to solve this problem

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that 
$$\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} {\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+...+\frac{1}{n+n}}=\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}{\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{1+\frac{k}{n}}}$$

This is a Riemann Sum for $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}$ over the interval $[0,1]$, with the satndard partition $x_i=\frac{k}{n}$ for $1 \leq k \leq n$ and the right hand points of the interval as intermediate points.

Therefore
$$\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} {\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+...+\frac{1}{n+n}}=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x}dx =\ln(1+x)|_0^1=\ln(2)$$

**P.S.** One can reach the came conclusion by using the well known identity
$$\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+...+\frac{1}{n+n}=\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...-\frac{1}{2n}$$ and the standard definition of the Euler -Mascheroni constant, but this approach is typically beyond calculus.

***Just for fun,*** here is how you get the limit with the E-M constant
$$\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+...+\frac{1}{n+n}=\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...-\frac{1}{2n}  \\
=\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{2n}-2 (\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+...+\frac{1}{2n})\\
=\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{2n}- (\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{n})\\
=\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{2n}- \ln(2n)- (\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{n} -\ln(n))+\ln(2) 
$$
This converges to $\gamma-\gamma+\ln(2)$.

Comment: Would you mind explaining why @N.Bar's answer won't be right? Because for me, that explanation seems reasonable. (So why the sum of infinite number of $0 ≠ 0$?)

Comment: If each term is going to $0$, but the number of terms is going to infinity, the sum is NOT necessarily going to 0. Intuitively, the hige number of terms can compensate for the fact that each term is getting smaller. @YanZhuang

Comment: Oh, so it is like one of the indeterminate forms introduced when learning L'hopitals'Rule: $0*\infty$ ? As a result, since we can't obtain a result back then, we can not say it equals to $0$ or $\infty$ here

Comment: I think that an emaple shows better the issue. What is the limit $$\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n}+...+\frac{1}{n}$$? Note that the sum is $n \cdot \frac{1}{n}$ which is exactly 1, the same approach as in that answer would show that this converges to 0.....

Comment: Yes I perfectly understand the issue here. I assume this is a typical trap on the exam that the professor put on there

Comment: @YanZhuang Yes, if the number of terms goes to infinity is exactly like there. Limit laws work nicely for finitely many terms, but in that case the number of terms goes to infinity, and each term goes to 0... It is similar in idea to the $\infty \cdot 0$ case from L'H..... This is an issue which appears sometimes in Calculus, and can be subtle until you see it once or twice.

Comment: @YanZhuang If you met Riemann Sums before, this is actually a nice, yet standard, problem about Riemann Sums. This is probably why your teacher put it on the exam.

Comment: Thank you very much! This thread can serve as a reminder for calculus students then!

Comment: Yes, I know about Riemann Sums but the prof is tricky enough because the other two limit sub-questions all require the use of L'hopital's rule, and there is another question below that is exclusively about Riemann Sums. So it creates the illusion that this doesn't involve Riemann Sums

Comment: Would you mind me asking, how are you able to see it is Riemann Sum when you see this question? And what did you do to realize this is a Riemann Sum of $\frac{1}{1+x}$ over the interval of $[0,1]$ ?

Comment: @YanZhuang Probably experience, seing enough RS you start recognizing them. Usually RS of integrals over $[0,1]$ look like $\frac{1}{n} \sum f(\frac{k}{n})$. All you have to realize is that, after you move the $\frac{1}{n}$ in front, the sum becomes exactly of this form.

Comment: Okay sure! I guess I will just have to practice more! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**Please Read: This is an incorrect answer. I will, however, leave it up to show a common mistake that can be made in this type of problem.**

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\frac{1}{n+3}+...+\frac{1}{n+n}$$

Remember that $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n} = 0$$

From this theorem, and by applying limit properties, you would get

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n+1}+\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n+2}+\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n+3}+...+\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n+n}$$

$$0+0+0+0+...$$
$$0$$

**What's the mistake? $0+0+0...$ is an indeterminate form**

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought too much when doing this problem.

Comment: But if this question is when x -> 0 or any other number, is this question still doable?

Comment: $0+0+0+..+0+...$ infinitely many times is NOT 0, it is an indeterminate form!

Comment: So this will be like a divergent series or it will have a definite answer? As I will eventually add up to 1/n ?

Comment: Note that $$\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\frac{1}{n+3}+...+\frac{1}{n+n} \geq \frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{2n}+...+\frac{1}{n+n} =\frac{1}{2}$$ This is definitely NOt converging to 0. @YanZhuang  On another hand, this is a standar Rieman sum, the limit is just the corresponding integral.

Comment: @N.S. Thanks for your comments. Obviously in my rush to answer I vastly oversimplified... I've upvoted your answer.

Comment: @YanZhuang Please see N.S.'s answer

Comment: It is actually easy to fall into this trap, I think I did it once too many years ago...

Answer (score 2):

If you know about harmonic numbers
$$S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac 1 {n+i}=H_{2 n}-H_n$$ For large values of $p$, we have
$$H_p=\gamma +\log \left({p}\right)+\frac{1}{2 p}-\frac{1}{12
   p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^4}\right)$$ Apply it twice and simply to get
$$S_n=\log (2)-\frac{1}{4 n}+\frac{1}{16 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^4}\right)$$ which shows the limit and how it is approached.

Moreover, this gives a quite good approximation of the partial sums. For example
$$S_{10}=\frac{155685007}{232792560}\approx 0.6687714$$ while the above truncated expansion would give
$$S_{10}\sim \log(2)-\frac{39}{1600}\approx 0.6687722$$